# Prolog - Consult actually cleans current state?

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I had the following code for customer creation and listing:

```
:-dynamic customer/2.

load:-consult('C:\\customers.txt').

save:-tell('C:\\customers.txt'), listing(customer), told.

%New customer
new_customer:-write("Name: "), read(Name), 
customer_code(Code), asserta(customer(Code, Name)), save.

customer_code(Code):- customer(C, _, _, _), Code is C + 1.
customer_code(1).
```

So far, so good. The problem is, when trying to do more complex search, filtering and reports in general, I had to use `retract` to clean the current memory state of the customers.

So, before any listing, I tend to consult the file again (calling `load`):

```
list_customers:- load, listing(customer).
```

What goes wrong here is that more times than not, this new load will cause the `listing` to repeat the last customer added to the database.

Eg:

C:\customers.txt:

```
:-dynamic customers/2
(2, 'John')
(1, 'Alicia')
```

listing(customers):

```
(2, 'John')
(2, 'John')
(1, 'Alicia')
```

I've been able to avoid this by using `retractall` before consulting:

```
load:- reatractall(customer(_,_)), consult('C:\\customers.txt').
```

Is this a good/bad practice? I don't quite understand what's going on here or why this solves the problem.

Comment: it's an hairy question: see [reconsult](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/reconsult.txt)/1

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you **must** use the Prolog database for this program? You will avoid a whole class of problems if you can re-design it so that you don't have to use `consult`, `assert`, `retract` etc.

Comment: Either way, a better solution to a separate, dynamic database might be to use a library like [library(persistency)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency).

Comment: I strongly support what Boris wrote: Avoid `assertz/1` etc. For your use case, you can simply use `include/1` to include an external database, and it is also read again when you reconsult. (SWI-Prolog: Try `make/0`.)

Comment: Thanks all for the advices.. sadly I'm in a course and this is the way this is supposed to be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consult predicate, as stated in the documentation in a rather obscure place that references to a deprecated [reconsult](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/reconsult.txt) clause, states that it will reload the clauses that *where loaded from the file*.

**What does this mean in this case?**

When you first create the entries in the text file, the clauses that *where loaded from the file* and the clauses that you created are the same.

The problem arises when you add a new entry. Let's check this with an example to make things clear:

**1)** You load the file with `consult`:

Now your database and the file will contain the same clauses:

customers.txt:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

Your Prolog database:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

So far, so good.

**2)** You add a new customer and save it to the file using `tell` / `told`:

customers.txt:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

Your Prolog database:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

Still, no issues. Here comes the real problem:

**3)** You reload the file:

customers.txt:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

Your Prolog database:

```
:- dynamic customer/2.

customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

Okay, what happened here? If you remember, we previously saw that `consult` reload clauses that *where loaded from the file*.

So, the clauses we reloaded are:

```
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```

This leaves us with a clause, `customer(5, 'Juan')`, that wasn't loaded from the file the first time. So now we have to add it to our database, thus resulting in:

```
customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(5, 'Juan').
customer(4, 'Juan').
customer(3, 'Juan').
customer(2, 'Juan').
customer(1, 'Juan').
```